# Chance of getting tails in the second throw with abnormal coin.

Tags: probability

You have one coin that is normal, and one coin that have "tails" on both sides. Then you choose a coin without knowing which one, and you flip it.

You get tails and decide to flip it again, what are the chances of getting tails the second time you throw it?

My calculations say that it's 3/4 of a chance to get tails the first time you throw it, but I can't figure out how the probability changes knowing you got tails the first time.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3/4$ for tails is indeed correct for the first throw. There's a $1/4$ chance you picked the fair coin and throw tails, and $2/4$ chance you picked the abnormal coin at first and threw tails. This means the probability of you having an abnormal coin for the second throw is $\frac{2}{4} / \frac{3}{4} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Notice that after seeing the first tails, you've got a higher chance of having picked the unfair coin. If this seems unintuitive, picture tossing hundreds of tails in a row - obviously one would be quite sure they picked the abnormal coin at that point, because such a sequence with a fair coin would be very unlikely.

So, having picked the abnormal coin with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and the fair one with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, the probability of getting tails is simply $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional probability (I assume that who flips the coin doesn't know what coin he is flipping even after the first flip). Let $A$ be the event that you get tail at the second flip and $B$ the event that you get tail at the first flip. The answer is:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac14+\frac12\cdot 1}{\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot1}=\frac{\frac58}{\frac34}=\frac56$$

Answer (score 0):

We can see that if $T_1$ is the event that coin 1 is tails and $T_2$ is the event that coin 2 is tails, then
$$
P(T_2\mid T_1)=P(T_2\mid T_1,\text{ abnormal})\cdot P(\text{abnormal}\mid T_1)+P(T_2\mid T_1,\text{ normal})\cdot P(\text{normal}\mid T_1)
$$
by the law of total probability.  So, what changes based on your knowledge that the first coin is heads?  The probabilities of the coin being normal vs abnormal!

Now, we know that $P(\text{normal}\mid T_1)=1-P(\text{abnormal}\mid T_1)$; so, let's just figure out $P(\text{abnormal}\mid T_1)$. We have
$$
P(\text{abnormal}\mid T_1)=\frac{P(\text{abnormal and }T_1)}{P(T_1)}.
$$
The event "abnormal and $T_1$" is really just the event "abnormal", since in the event that the coin is abnormal the first coin is definitely tails; so, $P(\text{abnormal and }T_1)=P(\text{abnormal})=\frac{1}{2}$. Further, $P(T_1)=\frac{3}{4}$, as you already computed. So, we get
$$
P(\text{abnormal}\mid T_1)=\frac{\,\frac{1}{2}\,}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{2}{3}.
$$
From this, we get $P(\text{normal}\mid T_1)=\frac{1}{3}$.

What remains is to compute $P(T_2\mid T_1,\text{ abnormal})$ and $P(T_2\mid T_1,\text{ normal})$. However, note that for these, the information that the first coin was tails no longer adds anything -- the probability of getting tails on the second throw is completely determined once you know whether the coin is normal or abnormal.